# NSAssert break on iOS target but not macOS target (workspace with multiple target)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

when "activate breakpoint" is OFF, 
NSAssert break on iOS target but not break on macOS target ?

Why is that and how to make the macOS target also break when NSAssert failed ( even when "activate breakpoint" is OFF) ?

Comment: Are you sure the macOS code yields to the same condition as the iOS code?

Comment: @Dirk yes cause it's NSAssert(false, @"message"), so condition is fixed, and also the code break when activate breakpoint is ON. the problem it's not break when it's OFF (on iOS on both cases it break)